# Как сверстать такую сетку карточек, вместе с кнопками?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, grid

[image: адаптивная сетка карточек]

Не получается сделать сетку именно такую, что бы размеры картинок были разные, при этом сохранялось количество элементов в строку.

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1vh;
}

.main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.project-cards {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: 0.4s linear;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  width: 30%;
}

img {
  height: 10vh;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: почитайте/посмотрите про `display: grid;`

Comment: Это называется Masonry Layout, есть готовые плагины js

Answer (score -1):

Без JS подгонять горизонтально не получится. Но если вас устроит другой порядок отображения картинок (сверху вниз, потом слева направо, как в газете) - попробуйте многоколоночную верстку:

```css
.container {
  background: wheat;
  column-count: 3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid coral;
  margin: 10px 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.image1 {
  min-height: 100px;
}

.image2 {
  min-height: 150px;
}

.image3 {
  min-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image image1" src="" alt="1" />
  <img class="image image2" src="" alt="2" />
  <img class="image image1" src="" alt="3" />
  <img class="image image2" src="" alt="4" />
  <img class="image image3" src="" alt="5" />
  <img class="image image1" src="" alt="6" />
  <img class="image image3" src="" alt="7" />
  <img class="image image2" src="" alt="8" />
  <img class="image image2" src="" alt="9" />
  <img class="image image1" src="" alt="10" />
  <img class="image image1" src="" alt="11" />
</div>
```

Comment: может, минусующий пояснит, что именно не нравится? Или это личная неприязнь?